# How to show that certain summations are primitive recursive?

Tags: computability, closure-properties, recursion, primitive-recursion

If we have a function $g\colon \mathbb{N}^{k+1} \to \mathbb{N}$  which is primitive-recursive. How to show that the function $f\colon \mathbb{N}^{k+1} \to \mathbb{N}$ with

$$f(x_1, \dots, x_k , x_{k+1})= \sum_{i=0}^{x_{k+1}}g(x_1,\dots, x_k,i)$$

is also primitive recursive?

Comment: You show how to implement it using the operations allowed in primitive recursion. Think of it as a kind of programming exercise.

Comment: So wouldn't it be possible to show it with some kind of induction?

Comment: Induction on what?

Comment: So we have a primitve recursive function $f$ and the composition and additon of primitive recursive function is also primitive recursive and with these operations would it be possible to define the rhs inductive?

Comment: @DavidRicherby If you want to derive it from first principle, induction on $k$ will happen at some point.

Comment: After providing an implementation, you should actually prove that it is correct. Unless the implementation is so direct that you can say it obviously computes the desired function. There induction could be used. Since you need to show this for infinitely many input values, induction is actually a good candidate.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a relevant discussion. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]? You may also want to check out our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599/).

Answer (score 0):

Primitive recursive means the function can be calculated using loops where the number of iterations is calculated ahead before running the loop.

So how often would you run the loop to calculate the sum?

Comment: This does not seem to constitute an answer. Plus, the criterion "is calculated ahead before running the loop" seems to be rather imprecise; calculated *how*?

Comment: Well, using primitive recursion, of course :-)